# R and appending to data frames

Tags: r

I have some cross correlation function crosscor, and I would like to loop through the function  for each of the columns I have in my data matrix. The function outputs some cross correlation that looks something like this each time it is run:

```
     Lags Cross.Correlation     P.value
     1     0     -0.0006844958 0.993233547
     2     1      0.1021006478 0.204691627
     3     2      0.0976746274 0.226628526
     4     3      0.1150337867 0.155426784
     5     4      0.1943150900 0.016092041
     6     5      0.2360415470 0.003416147
     7     6      0.1855274375 0.022566685
     8     7      0.0800646242 0.330081900
     9     8      0.1111071269 0.177338885
     10    9      0.0689602574 0.404948252
     11   10     -0.0097332533 0.906856279
     12   11      0.0146241719 0.860926388
     13   12      0.0862549791 0.302268025
     14   13      0.1283308019 0.125302070
     15   14      0.0909537922 0.279988895
     16   15      0.0628012627 0.457795228
     17   16      0.1669241304 0.047886605
     18   17      0.2019811994 0.016703619
     19   18      0.1440124960 0.090764520
     20   19      0.1104842808 0.197035340
     21   20      0.1247428178 0.146396407
```

I would like put all of the lists together so they are in a data frame, and ultimately export it into a csv file so the columns are as follows: lags.3, cross-correlation.3, p-value.3, lags.3, cross-correlation.2....etc. until p.value.50.

I have tried to use do.call as follows, but have not been successful:

```
    for(i in 3:50)
    {
        l1<-crosscor(data[,2], data[,i], lagmax=20)
        ccdata<-do.call(rbind, l1)
        cat("Data row", i)
    }
```

I've also tried just creating the data frame straight out, but am just getting the lag column names:

```
    ccdata <- data.frame()
    for(i in 3:50)
    {
        ccdata[i-2:i+1]<-crosscor(data[,2], data[,i], lagmax=20)
        cat("Data row", i)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an online source on data sets I could access to figure out how to do this? Best,

Answer (score 0):

There is a transpose method for data.frames. If "crosscor" is the name of the object just try this:

```
 tcrosscor <- t(crosscor)
 write.csv(tcrosscor, file="my_crosscor_1.csv")
```

The first row would be the Lag's; the second row, the Cross.Correlation's; the third row the P.value's. I suppose you could "flatten" it further so it would be entirely "horizontal" or "wide". Seems painful but this might go something like:

```
 single_line <- as.data.frame(unlist(tcrosscor))
 names(single_line) <- paste("Lag", 'Cross.Correlation', 'P.value'), rep(1:50, 3), sep=".")
 write.csv(single_line, file="my_single_1.csv")
```

Comment: Ah sorry I think my original questions was unclear. I actually figured out that I think the easiest way was just to merge each new data set I was creating with the previous one, rather than try to append to a new data set.